# jquery ui autocomplete not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I use the jQuery UI autocomplete fetching data from a Postgresql-database to populate an input-box (parzelle) with label-data. My form then submits the corresponding value-data, stored in a hidden input (gid).
My code works when the page is loaded the first time, sometimes even, when the page is reloaded after submitting the form. In most cases the autocomplete stops working after the first reload of the (same) page.

I use a quite simple modification of the example provided by [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp):

```
$( "#parzelle" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "./mapdata/get_parzellen_list_json.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        // prevent autocomplete from updating the input-box (parzelle)
        event.preventDefault();
        // update the input-box and hidden input (= gid)
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        $("#gid").val(ui.item.value);
      }
} );
```

Comment: you can share your json data..

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @CKG here is an example how my json-data looks like: [{"value": "3287", "label": "COMMUNE - CA - SECTION - Kuhrest - 508/82"}, {"value": "3284", "label": "COMMUNE - CB - SECTION - Diefenthal - 1325/1375"}, {"value": "3285", "label": "COMMUNE - CB - SECTION - In der Schlinder - 1605/705"}]

Comment: @Sam  In the console I get the following error: `TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function[Weitere Informationen]
<anonym>`. This error stays often even if I reload the site several times and then suddendly disappears and the autocomplete works like a charm. The jquery and jquery-ui are loaded at the end of the page immediately before my autocomplete code. I've tried to move the jquery-libs at the beginning, leaving my autocomplete.js at the end, but with no changing in the behaviour?

Comment: Are you using $(document).ready(function(){...}); ?

Comment: @Sam My code starts like this: `function init() {
    document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init); ` and ends with the following code: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);` But I don't use `$(document).ready(function(){...});`in my code. Where should I use it?

Comment: You need to ensure jQuery & jQuery UI is loaded before you call autocomplete. I believe this is your issue.

Comment: Is there a way to archieve this, to be shure both scripts are loaded?

Comment: Send me all of your code inside the <script> tags